# Add multiple Digital Signature in PDF using iTextSharp in C#

Tags: itext, digital-signature

I have implemented Digital Signature using iTextSharp Dll to sign PDF files with a single signature. Now, I want to add another digital signature in previously or already digitally signed PDF and I’m getting an error when verifying one signature.

How can I add multiple Digital Signature in one PDF and verify all signatures.

I’m using the following code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
using (FileStream fout = new FileStream(SignedFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    // appearance
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fout, '\0');
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
    //appearance.Reason = SignReason;
    //appearance.Location = SignLocation;
    appearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(xPos, yPos, xPos + 200, yPos + 100), PageNo, null);//.IsInvisible

    // Custom text and background image
    appearance.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(SignatureImg);
    appearance.ImageScale = 0.6f;
    appearance.Image.Alignment = 300;
    appearance.Acro6Layers = true;

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.Append("Digitally Signed by ");
    String name = SignerName;

    buf.Append(name).Append('\n');
    buf.Append("Date: ").Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"));

    string text = buf.ToString();

    appearance.Layer2Text = text;

    //digital signature
    IExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256");
    MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, es, new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { pk12.GetCertificate(alias).Certificate }, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

    stamper.Close();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code sample that works for the initial signature with different parameters? Like a new name for the field, a new bounding box.

Comment: Show us your code! Does the first signature allow extra digital signatures? (An author signature with level "no changes allowed" will break if you add an extra signature!) Did you add the second signature in append mode? (If you alter bytes in the original PDF, the first signature will break.) Your question is incomplete, hence the down-vote. Please read [the documentation](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html) first, then fix your question if something is still unclear.

Comment: *"previously or already digitally signed"* - do you mean different things by *previously signed* and *already signed*? If yes, please explain the difference when you improve the question as described by @Bruno.

Comment: @mkl - Previously Signed or Already Signed means... PDF which is to be signed by using itextsharp.dll or any PDF file which to be signed by other digital signature utility.

Comment: OK, I retracted the down-vote. Your problem is caused by "the user didn't read the documentation." See my answer to find out how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The error is in this line:

```
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fout, '\0');
```

Change it to:

```
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fout, '\0', true);
```

The explanation: you are not signing the document in append mode.

On further inspection of your code, I see that you're also adding an image. That can be tricky. Adding the new signature in append mode solves one problem. Adding that extra content could cause an extra problem depending on the version of iText you are using.

Comment: I have added the PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fout, '\0', null, true); in my code and it has been verified signature successfully. but it missed the image which I have added for signature... Please suggest.

Comment: If you didn't add an image, no image will be added. I'm not sure what kind of a response you expect to such an incomplete question.

Answer (score -1):

PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fout, '\0');

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.