# How to sign a pdf file with a .pem certificate?

Tags: c#, openssl, certificate, digital-signature

I generated a .pem certificate in a self-signed way with the private key inside. I have to apply the signature on a pdf file to test a code that actually checks that the signature is invalid.

I need a way to do this either in c# or with OpenSSL.

For example with OpenSSL I tried to use this

```
openssl cms -nosmimecap -md sha256 -binary -nodetach -cades -outform DER -sign -signer miocertificato.pem -inkey miachiaveprivata.key -in filedafirmare.pdf -out fileformato.pdf.p7m
```

but I had this error "cms: Unrecognized flag cades".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL is not capable of doing this!

In C# you can modify the bytes of the PDF as [specified](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSigDC/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf).

Alternatively you can build on open source like [iText Sharp, as in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41734958/add-multiple-digital-signature-in-pdf-using-itextsharp-in-c-sharp).

Or you can look out for commercial components - most of them support digital signatures.